# Why are my custom clang-tidy checks not showing up after adding custom module?

Tags: clang, clang-tidy

I have a few custom clang-tidy checks. For instance one in the `cppcoreguidelines` module and another in the `misc` module. They work fine. Now I extended clang-tidy by a custom module to organize them into.

When I rebuild, it succeeds but when I run `./clang-tidy -list-checks -checks=*`, my checks do not show up.

Here is what I did to add my custom module called `sw`:

- Created a subdirectory `sw` under `/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/`
- Updated `/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/CMakeLists.txt` by:

  - adding `add_subdirectory(sw)` right below `add_subdirectory(readability)`
  - listing `clangTidySWModule` inside the `set(ALL_CLANG_TIDY_CHECKS ...)` command
- Added `/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/sw/CMakeLists.txt` with the following content:

```cpp
set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
  FrontendOpenMP
  Support
  )

add_clang_library(clangTidySWModule
  AllCapsEnumeratorsCheck.cpp
  CatchByConstReferenceCheck.cpp
  SWTidyModule.cpp

  LINK_LIBS
  clangTidy
  clangTidyUtils

  DEPENDS
  omp_gen
  )

clang_target_link_libraries(clangTidySWModule
  PRIVATE
  clangAnalysis
  clangAST
  clangASTMatchers
  clangBasic
  clangLex
  clangTooling
  )
```

- Added `/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/sw/SWTidyModule.cpp` with the following content:

```cpp
#include "../ClangTidy.h"
#include "../ClangTidyModule.h"
#include "../ClangTidyModuleRegistry.h"
#include "AllCapsEnumeratorsCheck.h"
#include "CatchByConstReferenceCheck.h"

namespace clang {
namespace tidy {
namespace sw {

class SWModule : public ClangTidyModule {
public:
  void addCheckFactories(ClangTidyCheckFactories &CheckFactories) override {
    CheckFactories.registerCheck<AllCapsEnumeratorsCheck>(
        "sw-all-caps-enumerators");
    CheckFactories.registerCheck<CatchByConstReferenceCheck>(
        "sw-catch-by-const-reference");
  }
};

// Register the SWModule using this statically initialized variable.
static ClangTidyModuleRegistry::Add<SWModule>
    X("sw-module", "Adds my custom checks.");

} // namespace sw

// This anchor is used to force the linker to link in the generated object file
// and thus register the ReadabilityModule.
volatile int SWModuleAnchorSource = 0;

} // namespace tidy
} // namespace clang
```

I added the two checks `all-caps-enumerators` and `catch-by-const-reference` like I did under other modules before:

```
python3 add_new_check.py sw all-caps-enumerators
python3 add_new_check.py sw catch-by-const-reference
```

Am I missing something? Why are my checks not showing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I was missing [here](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/Contributing.html#registering-your-check). Hopefully this post will at least help others finding an answer quicker plus where to exactly add the missing piece.

I was missing the following in `/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/ClangTidyForceLinker.h`:

```cpp
// This anchor is used to force the linker to link the SWModule.
extern volatile int SWModuleAnchorSource;
static int LLVM_ATTRIBUTE_UNUSED SWModuleAnchorDestination =
    SWModuleAnchorSource;
```

Now my checks show up and I am happy (:

Answer (score 0):

Super helpful question and answer, but I have a complement to your answer.

Make sure to remember to create directories with the name of your new custom "module" of checks in these directories:

```
/clang-tools-extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/
```

```
/clang-tools-extra/test/clang-tidy/checkers/
```

Otherwise `add_new_check.py` fails halfway, do that and you are golden.